# Linq get object from one list where other list of integers are contained in the first list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following class structure:

```
public class Party {
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public List<int> PartyAgents {get;set;}
}
```

And a list of integers of PartyAgents => `public List<int> PartyAgentIds {get;set;}`

How can I get all parties where Party contains the party agents present in the list

I tried this:

```
var domainParties = (from party in _context.Party   //.Include("Address")
                                   where party.PartyAgents.Any(agent =>
                                         PartyAgentIds.Contains(agent))
                                   select party).ToList();
```

But this is throwing error

> The query  could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form
>   that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by
>   inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(),
>   ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: Try changing `_context.Party` to `_context.Party.ToList()`.

Comment: Are you sure your db structure looks like that... My "guess" its that PartyAgents is a collection navigation property to a child table, which makes the question totally different, and a solution different again

Answer (score -1):

Take #1 - a quick attempt to do this with a short snippet of code; has a reasonable chance of working with EF as only _context.Party.Where(p => p.PartyAgents.Contains(i) needs to be translated to SQL, but means running multiple queries :(

```
List<Party> domainParties = new List<Party>();
List<int> partyAgentIds = new List<int>{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }; 

partyAgentIds.ForEach( 
    (i) => domainParties.AddRange ( 
        _context.Party.Where(p => p.PartyAgents.Contains(i) 
        && !domainParties.Contains(p)
        )
    )
);
```

Take #2 - a dynamic expression should be more efficient as it makes the one query to the db. Have tested this specific code and it works against an IQueryable collection of the Party class, and I have also used this type of code previously with EF Core.

```
if (partyAgentIds.Count() > 0)
{
    ParameterExpression typeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Party));
    Expression propertyValue = Expression.Property(typeParam, typeof(Party).GetProperty("PartyAgents"));
    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();
    foreach(int i in partyAgentIds)
    {
        Expression containsValue = Expression.Constant(i, typeof(int));
        Expression expression = Expression.Call(propertyValue, containsMethod, containsValue);
        expressions.Add(expression);
    }

    Expression body = expressions.First();
    if (expressions.Count() > 1)
    {       
        for (int i = 1; i < expressions.Count; i++)
        { 
            Expression right = expressions.ElementAt(i);
            body = Expression.Or(body, right);
        }
    }

    //    Create the final criteria
    Expression<Func<Party, bool>> criteria = Expression.Lambda<Func<Party, bool>>(
        body,
        new ParameterExpression[] { typeParam });

        //    Now run the query with the criteria
        List<Party> results = _context.Party.Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```

Note - basic code provided as an example, to implement better break it out into a couple of generic classes so you can build proper dynamic expressions with type T and different operators and property types etc. Hope it is useful :)

Comment: And if you want to downvote, please show how you would do it better ;)

Comment: The OP's query is cleaner and easier to understand. The OP is having trouble because the query isn't being translated to SQL by EF. Your code has no hope of executing as SQL.

Comment: Don't agree with your first point, the second, maybe - I haven't tested with EF as I don't have a similar test project to hand. The code shows a different approach and the OP may get some mileage if he breaks it down into separate queries.

Comment: Looking at your previous answers it looks like you know your stuff, so I won't come down too heavily on this one. I just don't feel that this is one of your best.